# How do I fake uploading a file when testing Ruby Rack without the server?

Tags: ruby, rack, functional-testing

For testing, I send a Rack::Request straight to the app, not using the server.

```
def request_via_API( app, method, path, params={} ) # app should be API
  env = Rack::MockRequest.env_for( path, {:method => method, :params=>params}  )
  app.handle Rack::Request.new(env)
end
```

works great for testing direct input, but I'm stymied by file upload. My real system works great from the browser with a file upload. But now I want to test it via the API, and don't know how to get the file contents into the request via any of the Rack classes/methods. (I tried making sense of Rack::Test::UploadedFile but didn't succeed).

Thanks, Alistair

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were definitely on the right path. You can even use your function `request_via_API` without any modifications, e.g.:

```rb
request_via_API(app, 'POST', '/', {
  :field => "value",
  :text_source => Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile.new(PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE, MIME_TYPE_OF_YOUR_FILE)
})
```

This means you need to have some file somewhere. If you use fixtures, your test upload file should be around them. You can omit MIME time, but it defaults to `text/plain`.

If you use barebones Rack, you get the following hash after calling `Rack::Multipart.parse_multipart`:

```rb
{
  "field" => "value",
  "text_source" => {
    :filename => File.basename(PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE),
    :type => MIME_TYPE_OF_YOUR_FILE,
    :name => "text_source",
    :tempfile => Tempfile.new("RackMultipart"), # copied from PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE
    :head => "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text_source\"; filename=\"#{File.basename(PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE)}\"\r\n" +
             "Content-Type: #{MIME_TYPE_OF_YOUR_FILE}\r\n" +
             "Content-Length: #{BYTESIZE_OF_YOUR_FILE}\r\n"
  }
}
```

The `text_source` key can have any other name, of course.

[`Rack::MockRequest#env_for`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack/1.5.2/Rack/MockRequest.env_for) automatically tries to create multipart form data request if:

- HTTP method is not GET
- there is no `:input` option provided
- `:params` option is a `Hash`
- `:params` option values contain at least one instance of [`Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack/1.5.2/Rack/Multipart/UploadedFile)

You can see the details in the source code [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/mock.rb#L102) and [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/generator.rb#L29).

I think relying on multipart request generation by `Rack::MockRequest` and `Rack::Multipart` is useful only for mocking HTML forms with file upload and file upload mechanisms that act the same. So, there's no need to use `Rack::Multipart#build_multipart` or `Rack::Multipart::Generator` directly.

If you have more complicated multipart scenarios or different file upload mechanism, you must pass `opts` argument with `:input` key instead of `:params` to [`Rack::MockRequest#env_for`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack/1.5.2/Rack/MockRequest.env_for). How you generate that value for `:input` is your problem as far as Rack mocking capabilities are concerned. It only wraps it in [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) if it is a `String` as you can see [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/mock.rb#L126). Otherwise, it is the same thing that will be passed as `rack.input` in the Rack environment hash and therefore it must conform to the [Rack input stream spec](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC#The_Input_Stream) (i.e., be an `IO`-like object).

Because this was also quite a challenge for me and I used it as an exercise to deepen my knowledge of Rack I created a [simple project on GitHub](https://github.com/f4z4onZH27/fake-rack-upload) to explore this file upload mocking.

*Note*: I tried to fix everything to Rack 1.5.2 except for the link to the Rack SPEC (so beware). Links to Ruby StdLib lead to the current version.

Comment: just use Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new it will use multipart class when needed.

Comment: Well, it didn’t work for Alistair and I find it useless to go this path since Rack already has capability of mocking file upload and multipart requests.  Rack::Test gem is definitely useful, but, in my opinion, not in this small simple case.